# BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I started to read Spring in **Action by Craig Walls** and after Chapter 1 I tried to make this simple example work, I have the next XML configuration:

```
<bean id="knight" class="com.tutorialspoint.BraveKnight">
    <constructor-arg ref="quest"/>
</bean>

<bean id="quest" class="com.tutorialspoint.SaveAPrincess">
    <constructor-arg value="#{T(System).out}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="minstrel" class="com.tutorialspoint.Minstrel">
    <constructor-arg value="#{T(System).out}"/>
</bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="minstrel">
        <aop:pointcut id="embark" expression="execution(* *.embarkOnQuest(..))"/>

        <aop:before pointcut-ref="embark" method="singBeforeQuest"/>

        <aop:after pointcut-ref="embark" method="singAfterQuest"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

And I do the following to get the knight bean:

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
        BraveKnight knight = context.getBean(BraveKnight.class);
        knight.embarkOnQuest();
    }
}
```

And when I run this I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'knight' defined in class path resource [Beans.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#e320068' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#e320068': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'embark' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embark': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:497)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:758)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
```

Comment: what version of aspectj/aspectj weaver are you using? You need aspectj runtime and weaver I believe

Comment: Did not know that, I thought it's already built in the Spring framework..

Comment: It might be, although the fact that you're getting a no class def founderror suggests it is not available... what Sprint Version are you using?

Comment: It was because I did not have installed AspectJ, thank you :)